# I need help reverse engineering my ereader (trying to get into the shell)

Tags: firmware, linux, firmware-analysis

I'm trying to reverse engineer my E-Reader. It's a Denver EBO-620. I want to change the off screen image and add my own fonts. With help of [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/hardwarehacking/comments/glxian/is_it_possible_to_modify_my_ereader_so_i_can_add/) I've managed to log the startup sequence (shown down here), but I'm not sure what my next steps should be.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
    =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2020.05.27 18:56:10 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
   Âÿ ÿHELLO! BOOT0 is starting!
initializing SDRAM OK.
NAND_RequestDMA  ok
Succeed in opening nand flash.
Succeed in reading Boot1 file head.
The size of Boot1 is 0x00034000.
The file stored in 0X00000000 of block 2 is perfect.
Check is correct.
Ready to disable icache.
Succeed in loading Boot1.
Jump to Boot1.
begin to init file system
bat vol = 4046
1
NB1 : enter NFB_Init

nand_for_boot1.c 135get the good blk ratio from hwscan : 631571392 

NB1 : enter phy init

[NAND] nand driver version: 0x0x00000002, 0x0x00000011, data: 0x20120926

NAND_RequestDMA  ok

[SCAN_DBG] Nand flash chip id is:0x0x0000002c 0x0x00000044 0x0x00000044 0x0x00000000 0x0x8042506c 0x0x0000004b





[SCAN_DBG] ==============Nand Architecture Parameter==============

[SCAN_DBG]    Nand Chip ID:         0x0x4b44442c 0x0xffffffff

[SCAN_DBG]    Nand Chip Count:      0x0x00000001

[SCAN_DBG]    Nand Chip Connect:    0x0x00000001

[SCAN_DBG]    Nand Rb Connect Mode:      0x0x00000001

[SCAN_DBG]    Sector Count Of Page: 0x0x00000010

[SCAN_DBG]    Page Count Of Block:  0x0x00000100

[SCAN_DBG]    Block Count Of Die:   0x0x00000800

[SCAN_DBG]    Plane Count Of Die:   0x0x00000002

[SCAN_DBG]    Die Count Of Chip:    0x0x00000001

[SCAN_DBG]    Bank Count Of Chip:   0x0x00000001

[SCAN_DBG]    Optional Operation:   0x0x00000008

[SCAN_DBG]    Access Frequence:     0x0x00000028

[SCAN_DBG]    ECC Mode:             0x0x00000005

[SCAN_DBG]    Read Retry Type:      0x0x00000000

[SCAN_DBG]    DDR Type:             0x0x00000000

[SCAN_DBG] =======================================================



[SCAN_DBG] ==============Optional Operaion Parameter==============

[SCAN_DBG]    MultiPlaneReadCmd:      0x0x00000000, 0x0x00000030

[SCAN_DBG]    MultiPlaneWriteCmd:     0x0x00000011, 0x0x00000080

[SCAN_DBG]    MultiPlaneCopyReadCmd:  0x0x00000000, 0x0x00000000, 0x0x00000035

[SCAN_DBG]    MultiPlaneCopyWriteCmd: 0x0x00000085, 0x0x00000011, 0x0x00000080

[SCAN_DBG]    MultiPlaneStatusCmd:    0x0x00000070

[SCAN_DBG]    InterBnk0StatusCmd:     0x0x00000078

[SCAN_DBG]    InterBnk1StatusCmd:     0x0x00000078

[SCAN_DBG]    BadBlockFlagPosition:   0x0x00000001

[SCAN_DBG]    MultiPlaneBlockOffset:  0x0x00000001

[SCAN_DBG] =======================================================

NB1 : nand phy init ok

src\format\nand_format.c 2623[FORMAT_ERR] format nand flash*********!

PHY_PageReadSpare : too much ecc err,bank 0x00000000 block 0x00000000,page 0x00000001 

PHY_PageReadSpare : too much ecc err,bank 0x00000000 block 0x00000000,page 0x00000000 

NB1 : init ok

mount successfully.
0
Source clock is HOSC, preScale=64, interval=375

 Mount Parts Thread runniMInit : enter init nand flash driver
 nand driver version: 0x2 0x11
 nand_drv.c 166 ---------------
 ------
  nand_drv.c 192 --nand disk size: 0x780000

 partition [D] plug in..

 partition [Z] plug in..
 Mount Parts Thread work now.....

 partition [E] plug in..
 Mount Parts Thread work end....
 $$$$ eink clock is 8 $$$$$
 eink_GetFileCntFromDir path = v:\
 eLIBs_opendir failed!
 AWF fp=0
 -------------open awf file failed, try to open backup awf-----------
 AWF file length=545 K
 LCD TCON OPEN
 MSG:L3723(Drv_eink.c): set vcom mode as IO contrl, not pwm
 .....................................................................................................................
 .Please press enter key(keypad or irkey) to continue!
..............................................................
 .....................................................................................................................
 Esh_StartUp 
 ===================yyparse start====================
 yynerrs.1 =  0 
 yynerrs.2 =  0 
 outtree->op_type =  1 
 yynerrs.3 =  0 
 &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&yyparse end&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
 Execute startup script begin..............
 ===================yyparse start====================
 yynerrs.1 =  0 
 yynerrs.2 =  0 
 outtree->op_type =  -382909968 
 yynerrs.3 =  0 
 &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&yyparse end&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
 ===================yyparse start====================
 yynerrs.1 =  0 
 yynerrs.2 =  0 
 outtree->op_type =  1 
 yynerrs.3 =  0 
 &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&yyparse end&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
 Esh Error:  OpenConfigFile y:\config\config.bin failed.
 ===================yyparse start====================
 yynerrs.1 =  0 
 yynerrs.2 =  0 
 outtree->op_type =  -382909968 
 yynerrs.3 =  0 
 &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&yyparse end&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
 ===================yyparse start====================
 yynerrs.1 =  0 
 yynerrs.2 =  0 
 outtree->op_type =  1 
 yynerrs.3 =  0 
 &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&yyparse end&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
 ===================yyparse start====================
 yynerrs.1 =  0 
 yynerrs.2 =  0 
 outtree->op_t41 set tmpNewCpu = 37yynerrs.3 =  0 
 &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&yyparse end&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
 ===================yyparse start====================
 yynerrs.1 =  0 
 yynerrs.2 =  0 
 outtree->op_type =  1 
 yynerrs.3 =  0 
 &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&yyparse end&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
 ===================yyparse start====================
 yynerrs.1 =  0 
 yynerrs.2 =  0 
 outtree->op_type =  -382909968 
 yynerrs.3 =  0 
 &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&yyparse end&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
 ===================yyparse start====================
 yynerrs.1 =  0 
 yynerrs.2 =  0 
 outtree->op_type =  1 
 yynerrs.3 =  0 
 &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&yyparse end&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
 ...............Execute startup script end
 Esh_StartUp finish
 Esh msg:  shell maidesktop_server_init plug tp start
 desktop_server_init plug tp over
 dsk_orchid_createDisk over
 d_createDisk over
  dsk_orchid_check over
 dsk_voice_set_volume over
 dsk_display_set_lcd_bright over
 dsk_keytone_init over
 dsk_keytone_set_state over
 dsk_app_reg_init over
 dsk_langres_set_type over
 214 Date parameter is invalid!(Y2020, M5, D28)
 214 Date parameter is invalid!(Y2020, M5, D28)
 214 Date parameter is invalid!(Y2020, M5, D28)

 eink_GetFileCntFromDir path = v:\
 eLIBs_opendir failed!
 AWF fp=0
 -------------open awf file failed, try to open backup awf-----------
 AWF file length=545 K
 LCD TCON OPEN
 MSG:L3723(Drv_eink.c): set vcom mode as IO contrl, not pwm
 LCD TCON close
 B þ           `     €ÿ
```

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to say that this ereader indeed runs on an allwinner E200 chip. So most likely it's the allwinner os (probably 2.0, but that's not sure).

Answer (score 1):

The boot log seems similar to the one [from this page](https://linux-sunxi.org/FEL), so there's a high possibility this device is using an AllWinner SoC. You can try the tools from the [linked repository](https://github.com/linux-sunxi/sunxi-tools).

Another option could be to dump the flash and analyze it.